# How do you interpret the infinite activity property of variance gamma process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, gamma-function, levy-processes, digamma-function

I am a little bit confused with the infinite activity property of variance gamma(VG) process $X(t),$ where $$X(t)=\theta G(t) + \sigma W(G(t)),$$ for any finite interval, the VG process has infinitely many jumps. 
My current understanding is:
For any $h>0$, we can find a $\varepsilon$ such that $|X(t+h)-X(t)|>\varepsilon$, and as $h \rightarrow 0$, $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, which means for any time step $h$, there exist a small jump, and the magnitude of the jumps becomes infinitesimally small as the rate of jumps tends to infinity. Am I right?
In another hand, I also have question about the Gamma process, from Wiki I found the Gamma process often write as $\Gamma (t;\gamma ,\lambda )$, what is the expression of $\Gamma (t;\gamma ,\lambda )$? And what does Gamma process mean, does it mean the jump size during a time step $t$?

Comment: What are $G$ and $W \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: G is Gamma process and W is Brownian motion.

Comment: By "infinite jumps" I take it you mean "infinitely many jumps." I.e. there is no jump that is by itself an "infinite jump". But you should phrase that as "infinitely many jumps."

Answer (score 1):

This will be a partial answer.

First, there are things to know about jumps of monotone functions before you get into anything involving probability.

- A nowhere decreasing function cannot have any discontinuities other than jumps.
- The set of jumps that it has in each interval in its domain is either finite or countably infinite; it cannot be uncountably infinite.
- In every interval $I$ in the domain and for every positive number $a,$ the number of jumps of size at least $a$ that such a function has within the interval $I$ is finite.

And there are things to know about the gamma distribution before getting into the gamma process:

- The gamma distribution is this probability distribution: $$ \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} (\lambda x)^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda x} (\lambda\, dx) \quad\text{for } x>0. $$ The two parameters $\alpha,\lambda$ are positive.
- The reason why $\alpha-1$ rather than $\alpha$ is seen in the exponent is that if two independent random variables have gamma distributions with parameters $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ then their sum has a gamma distribution with parameter $\alpha_1+\alpha_2,$ and similarly for more than two.

Now break a time interval of length $\alpha$ into tiny time intervals of lengths $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n.$ Let the value of a random process at time $0$ be $0,$ and let its value at time $\alpha_1$ be a gamma-distributed random variable with parameter $\alpha_1,$ and let its value at time $\alpha_1+\alpha_2$ be the sum of that first gamma-distributed random variable and another, independent of it, with paramater $\alpha_2,$ and so on, and similarly if one breaks that short interval of length $\alpha_1$ into yet smaller intervals. This is an infinitely divisible process. Such is the gamma process.

The value of the expression $\Gamma(t;\gamma,\lambda)$ is the value of such a process at time $t$ when the $\alpha$ parameter is $\gamma t.$ Thus for every $t>0,$ $\Gamma(t;\gamma,\lambda)$ is a random variable whose distribution is the gamma distribution above with $\alpha=\lambda t.$

That value is the sum of all of the jump sizes between time $0$ and time $t.$